# I am having trouble with CSS auto heights and floating divs

Tags: css, html

So I have a simple `<div class="main">` and I have a set of 6 smaller div's within. All of these smaller div's are set to float:left; as to create a little tiled list, however this messes with my auto height and seems to not 'count' as something in the div. Please could you help me  either correct my code or let me know if there is a better way!

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="service-items">
      <div class="service-item">WEB DESIGN</div>
      <div class="service-item">SEO</div>
      <div class="service-item-right">WEB GUIDANCE</div>
      <div class="service-item">GRAPHIC DESIGN</div>
      <div class="service-item">BROCHURE DESIGN</div>
      <div class="service-item-right">CONTACT ME!</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width:930px;
    height:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    padding:10px;   
}

.service-items {
    width:930px;
    height:auto;    
}

.service-item {
    width:200px;
    height:90px;
    padding-top:90px;
    margin-right:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size:150%;
    background-color:#69F;
    display:block;  
}
```

Comment: None ... of your code indicates anything being floated.

Comment: Added http://jsfiddle.net/yEvH6/ pls see and explain what u want exactly

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=containing+floats

Comment: I am sorry about that, I removed it as it was ruining the page and forgot to re-add it!! My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floated elements do indeed not add to the parents height. There are a bunch of clearfix-hacks to get around this in more complicated (namely, overflow hidden prevents other, overlapping elements like custom tooltips from being shown) cases.

In your case, a simple `overflow: hidden` should do the trick.

```
.service-items {
    width:930px;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden; // Set this
}
```